# Warsaw theme subsection alignment

Tags: beamer, themes

In Warsaw theme, subsections are left-aligned but I want right-aligned subsections in the Warsaw theme headline.

Comment: Hi Pratiksha, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show a little bit, what you already did and where in the theme the subsections are left-aligned and you want them right aligned (maybe you could draw a small picture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Warsaw` beamer theme loads `shadows` outer theme which in turn loads the `split` outer theme. In the file `beamerouterthemesplit.sty` wen can find

```
\usesectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill\insertsectionhead}
  {\hfill\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
```

Than ensures the section title is right aligned within its half of the header. Wen can now adapt this code as follows

```
\usesubsectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill\insertsubsectionhead}
  {\hfill\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsubsectionhead}
```

in order to also right align the subsection headings inside of their half of the header and add the before mentioned code to the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usesubsectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill\insertsubsectionhead}
  {\hfill\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsubsectionhead}

\begin{document}
\section{section heading}
\subsection{subsection heading}
\begin{frame}
frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]